# prepend map with new key/value pair

Tags: javascript

How to prepend a key/value pair to the beginning of a javascript Map object?

```
var fields = new Map([
    ['product_type', {
        value : 'PRODUCT'
    }],
    ['supplier_product_type', {
        value : 'INTERNAL'
    }]
]);
```

I want to add a new key to the beginning of the Map so it will end up like this

```
[
    ['new_key', {
        value : 'new value'
    }],
    ['product_type', {
        value : 'PRODUCT'
    }],
    ['supplier_product_type', {
        value : 'INTERNAL'
    }]
]
```

Comment: Why are you using a `Map` to store an ordered list of values? that's pretty much the definition of an `Array`? So what's the `Map` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible. According to the specs on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), insertion order matters but there are no methods for insers except at the tail.

Answer (score -3):

As documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) the Javascript Map object is an unsorted Map. The item order is by insertion (but must be considered random).

If you need a sorted Map you can implement it by yourself or pick up a ready to use lib like [this one](https://github.com/monmohan/dsjslib)

Comment: Be informed that this is no longer the case as of ES6